# Use of object <type 'object'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

In **python**, we all know that there are the general `object` type, of which every class is naturally a heir.

If we type `object` in console, it returns `type <'object'>`.

```
>>> object
<type 'object'>
```

So far, so good.
It is also possible to instantiate a variable of type `object`

```
>>> var = object()
>>> var
<object object at 0x021684D8>
```

My question is:

Is there a reason for the `object` type being instantiable? Is there any use for this? Or is it just made for the sake of formality?

Comment: You could look at it the other way around: given that types in general can be instantiated, what reason would there be for special-casing `object` to *not* be instantiable?

Comment: Because you can create subclasses of `object` that can be instantiated.

Comment: This is kind of a C++ way of thinking.  In C++ you can make abstract base classes, similar to Java Interfaces that declare methods but don't define them.  You can't instantiate these unless you subclass them and implement all the required methods.  Python just doesn't work like this: you can generally instantiate anything, but if you call an undefined method you get an error.

Comment: @Evan: But Python does have abstract base classes, and you can't instantiate those. See the `abc` module, and `collections.abc` and `numbers` for practical examples.

Comment: @Evan One way to look at the difference between C++ and Python is that Python ABCs are a sort of "extra" thing, not a fundamental part of the class system. But another way to look at it is that there just aren't any obviously useful abstract methods for a root class to require all subclasses to instantiate, so a root class doesn't have any reason to be abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one practical reason to instantiate `object`: it's a quick, easy, and idiomatic way to get a value that will not compare equal to any other value (and will raise an exception of you try an ordering comparison). This makes it a perfect sentinel. For example:

```
last = object()
for value in iterable:
    if value != last:
        yield value
        last = value
```

If you used `None` as a sentinel value, it would do the wrong thing if `iterable` started with `None`, but there's no way `iterable` can start with the brand-new `object` instance you just created.

---

However, even if there were no practical use for `object` instances, consider that every instance of a subclass of an `object` is an `object`, so conceptually you're creating `object` instances all the time--and practically, if you're designing a subclass that uses `super()` in its `__init__` or `__new__` this is no longer just conceptual. If `object.__init__` were unavailable, or raised, you'd have to create a new do-nothing root class for any hierarchy of cooperative classes just to have a do-nothing base implementation.

Comment: Wow, I have never though of that. But, why would I want to compare `if value != last` knowing that it will always return `True` ?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso That's only for the first `value`.

Comment: It won't always return true. For example, if `iterable` is `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]`, it'll be true for `1 != object()`, then false for `1 != 1`, then true for `2 != 1` and `3 != 2`, then false for `3 != 3`, so you'll yield 1, 2, and 3, removing all adjacent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=0
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=1
A=a()
B=b()
type(A)
type(B)
```

It will return it:

```
<class '__main__.a'>
<class '__main__.b'>
```

This tells what kind of object is that.

Comment: I know, but that has nothing to do with the question! But thanks anyway :)